# How can I prevent a component from handling collision events?

Tags: unity, events

In Unity, I can set the `enabled` flag of a component to `false`, and this prevents Unity from running the `Update` method of the component. 
However, Unity still runs other methods of the component, such as `OnTriggerEnter2D`. 
Is there a way to completely disable a component (without removing it), such that it does not get any events at all?

Of course I can manually add a flag to my component, and check this flag from within the event handlers, but I would like to know if there is a built-in solution.

Comment: Have you considered to just disable the Collider? Or perhaps put the component in a sub object and deactivate that sub-object with `SetActive(false)`?

Comment: Disabling the collider will also prevent collision events from all the other components attached to the same object. I want to disable only a specific component. Putting the component in a sub-object is indeed possible, if there is no more natural way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The engine will always send these collision messages, [by design](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html):

> Collision events will be sent to disabled MonoBehaviours, to allow enabling Behaviours in response to collisions.

If you don't want your script to process the event when it's disabled, that's in your control to express in your script:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    if(!enabled) return;

    // ...the rest of your collision response goes here.
}
```

Philipp's recommendation to put the script on a separate object you can deactivate as a whole is also a good one, if you need a more blanket-level shutdown rather than surgically disabling just specific handlers.